# How to convert data to Json in MVC 5 app using jQuery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

The code looks as following:

1) The entity class:

```
public partial class EnergeticalComplex : TrackableBaseObject, IWithDbAffiliateFieldBlockField
{
    private ICollection<Cell> _cells;
    private ICollection<Document> _documents;

    public int? AffiliateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Affiliate Affiliate { get; set; }

    public int? FieldBlockId { get; set; }
    [AutoQueryRoot]
    public virtual FieldBlock FieldBlock { get; set; }

    public int? FieldId { get; set; }
    [AutoQueryRoot]
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    [AutoQueryRoot]
    public virtual ICollection<Cell> Cells
    {
        get { return _cells ?? (_cells = new List<Cell>().WithLock(SyncRoot)); }
    }

    [NotNull]
    [TrackableRelation]
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents
    {
        get { return _documents ?? (_documents = new List<Document>().WithLock(SyncRoot)); }
    }
}
```

2) In controller:

```
public JsonResult ComboBoxBalanse(int fieldId)
{
    List<EnergeticalComplex> eComplex;
    using (var c = _contextFactory.CreateContext())
    {
        var eComplexesSet = c.Set(c.GetType()
            .EntityTypes()
            .First(t => typeof(IEnergeticalComplex).IsAssignableFrom(t)));
        eComplex = eComplexesSet
            .Cast<EnergeticalComplex>()
            .Where(ec => ec.Field.Id == fieldId && !ec.Name.Contains("KTP"))
            .ToList();
    }

    ViewData["EnergeticalComplexList"] = eComplex;
    ViewData["fieldId"] = fieldId;

    return Json(eComplex, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

3) In JavaScript module:

```
function onClickShowButton() {
    var selectBoxField = $("#divFieldsComboBox").dxSelectBox("instance");
    var indField = selectBoxField.option("value");

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/LostEnergyCalculation/ComboBoxBalanse',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "{ fieldId: " + indField + " }"
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

The program flow doesn't enter block after .done().

Comment: _after_ `.done()`, Please elaborate. What is the output of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: did you check console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I've added .fail() block with console.log(data) and got this: ReferenceError: data is not defined.

Comment: It seems ajax cannot handle the entity class.

Comment: debug your code and check if the `eComplex` you're using is correct. as you are using it outside of context, the object is already disposed

Comment: The eComplex is ok. I've tried without using and got the same error.

Comment: the error you've posted is about the object being disposed...so I think it's related to the way you're retrieving your data.

Comment: try this in ajax call `data: { fieldId:  indField }`

Comment: @Nagaraj S: I've already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, in Response section there's some error about cycling reference during serialization of System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Affiliate_012C2624DEB9D968B24955F14CCF752EA44FC9B0C55B77A19B56416C2EF598C8 object. It refers to the entity class we use.

Comment: Do you need all properties from `EnergeticalComplex`?

Comment: No. And it means I need to create new simpler class that takes necessary properties from EnergeticalComplex class and use that simpler class.

Comment: exactly. Or just create an anonymous variable from the list with those properties and return this variable.

Comment: @tesicg yes that's a good idea. This concept, within MVC, is usually known as creating a ViewModel.

Comment: probably you may use one of the class mappers

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. That's good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using entity class which have further class's member variables! 
In this case there is possibility of JSon serialization problem due to Circular reference in your 'eComplex' object.
To prevent this declare new class without all sub-classes member variables or use `.Select()` to take only required elements.
i.e.In your Controller

```
eComplex = eComplexesSet
            .Cast<EnergeticalComplex>()
            .Where(ec => ec.Field.Id == fieldId && !ec.Name.Contains("KTP"))
            .Select(m=> new {
             VariableName = m.ModelVariableName,
             // Same for elements which you needed for 
             });
```